# Using accelerometer data in a vehicle to vehicle Kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter, estimation

I've been working on building a Kalman filter to determine the positions of nearby vehicles. Each vehicle is equipped with four distance-measuring sensors, which are used to measure its distance from other vehicles, as shown in the figure below. It's worth noting that the measurements may exceed the actual values if the sensors are not in a direct line of sight.

[V2V measurement illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBJUi.png)

I have implemented an Extended Kalman Filter that relies solely on distance measurements to estimate the location of each vehicle. Given that each vehicle is mobile and their x and y axes do not align, and there are no stationary devices to be used as reference points, I'm wondering if would it be possible incorporate accelerometer, gyroscope or some other sensor data into the state estimation process.